# How to use JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Ok, I'm sure this might not be the right place to ask this but I need clear answers and fast, because I'm working on an assignment that necessitates the use of JList.  I want to have a displayed list of what appear to be strings, each of which, when clicked, will display the data of a custom class I have created called Message.  In other words, I want individual messages to be automatically linked to each entry in the list, and when an entry is clicked on, Message.show() is called (which will just display the data in a readable form).  How do I do this?

I'm not really sure how to declare a JList, how to have it automatically update when a message is deleted, or how to have each entry display a string while simultaneously being able to link to a message object.

Comment: `but I need clear answers and fast,` - that is irrelevant to the question. People will answer questions when they have the time and they know the answer. The fact that you leave the assignment to the last minute is your problem. Therefore, my answer will only point you in the right direction. It will still be up to you to actually do the reading of the tutorial.

Comment: Show what you try

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use a `HashMap` to store your data. The key would be the String being displayed in the JList. Then the value would be the other text you want to display.

Then you can add a `ListSelectionListener` to the JList. Whenever the selection changes you get the currently selected value from the JList and use that as the key to access the data in your `HashMap`.

> I'm not really sure how to declare a JList, how to have it automatically update when a message is deleted

You delete the data from the `ListModel`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example showing how to add/remove data from the model.

The tutorial also has a section on `How to Write a ListSelectionListener` to get you started.